# How to make ES modules import from a Lambda layer work?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, es6-modules, aws-lambda-layers

I have a lambda function in node v14 that imports AWS SDK v3 from a lambda layer.

In my function I can use my node modules from the layer only if I use CommonJS syntax:

```
const { parseUrl } = require('@aws-sdk/url-parser');
```

Using ES modules doesn't work.

```
import { parseUrl } from '@aws-sdk/url-parser';
```

It will throw an error:
`"errorMessage": "Cannot find package '@aws-sdk/url-parser' imported from /var/task/index.js\nDid you mean to import @aws-sdk/url-parser/dist-cjs/index.js?"`

It should work. I have `"type": "module"` in `package.json` and locally the import works.
It also starts working when I specify the full path to cjs index file:

```
import { parseUrl } from '/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@aws-sdk/url-parser/dist-cjs/index.js';
```

Which is really weird.

I checked `NODE_PATH` and `/opt/nodejs/node_modules` is there so I don't know where the problem is.

The full implementation is here so you can replicate the error:
https://github.com/simon-q/lambda-layer-es-modules-error

Is it something broken in lambda layers or am I doing something wrong?
I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Found this tweet about the bug https://twitter.com/coderbyheart/status/1486470882008645634?s=20&t=Vtq1BPfn1wfM2hc0mpKnDw

Comment: Have a look at this github https://github.com/vibe/aws-esm-modules-layer-support

Comment: Thanks, Vive's github post save the day after hours spinning around this bug.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't help if you're stuck on an older runtime version, but as announced in [this November 2022 blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-18-x-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/), the Node.js 18.x runtime introduces support for ES module resolution using `NODE_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

it's a path error for files in node_modules folder. [In this link](https://github.com/vibe/aws-esm-modules-layer-support) you can get more details about the problem.

I created a serverless plugin that fixes it automatically, hope it helps someone. Follow the link: https://www.npmjs.com/serverless-esm-layer